# How do I fix a mysql table that doesn't exist but thinks it does

Tags: mysql

There's a table in a database of mine, let's call it `table_x`, that used to get created and destroyed all the time. Now that's not happening, so the table should either exist or not, and actually it should not.

When I try to get a mysqldump of the database I systematically get this error:

```
Error: Couldn't read status information for table table_x ()
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show create table `table_x`': Table 'xxxxx.table_x' doesn't exist (1146)
```

Like mysqldump for some reason still thinks that the table exists and when it tries to dump it it triggers the error.

`SHOW TABLES` does NOT show the table.
However in `information_schema.TABLES` it's present.

I guess that's the problem, that `information_schema` somehow got out of sync with reality.

How do I "repair" this inconsistency?

I tried deleting the table with

```
DROP TABLE table_x
```

but unsurprisingly I get an error that the table doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you try mysqlcheck --repair --use-frm --all-databases

Answer (score -1):

To avoid such kind of error during drop a table it's a good habit to use IF Exist and IF NOT EXIST as:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_x;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST table_x;
```